# Is it normal that I can't erase an input to FZF?

Tags: plugin-fzf, fzf

I am using the FZF vim plugin and when I open it using `:FZF<cr>` it then shows me the prompt to input what I want to search for. If I type something and then press backspace to erase (For example because I made a typo in what I want to search for) the window just closes.

Is this normal?

Comment: (I don't think so, but) you might have better luck asking on their issue tracker.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue? if so, will you please share the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't the normal behavior for fzf.vim. I was able to backspace normally to delete typed text.

Check your mappings by running `:map <Backspace>`.